# Bottom sheet is not hiding completely android?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am using bottom sheet with the following properties in my layout

```
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="16dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

It is visible to peek height when the screen is opened. And user can drag it to expand.
On button click I want to hide it completely.
I am using the below code to hide but it isn't working

```
sheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0)
sheetBehavior.isHideable=true
sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
```

The bottom sheet collapses to its original peek height rather than fully disappearing.

Comment: If you want programmatically you can use just sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @mosyonal I could resolve it by simply the follwoing

```
 sheetBehavior.isHideable = true
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
```